# Responsive card-overlay on carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a login/signup card on top of a carousel. But my margins are hardcoded and everything seems really complex. It looks fine on desktops but on phones/tablets, it's not responsive. I'm ultra new to webdev and have just learnt for like two weeks, so pardon my lack of knowledge.

This is my html code:

```html
<div id="carouselFinal" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="false">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class=" carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images3.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images4.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images5.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images7.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./../assets/images8.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card mt-3 tab-card">
          <div class="card-header tab-card-header">
            <label style="font-size:x-large; margin-top: 10px;">Signup</label>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist" style="float: right;">
              <li>
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#one" role="tab" aria-controls="One" aria-selected="true"
                  class="btn btn-dark" style="color:white">
                  <</a> </li> <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#two" role="tab" aria-controls="One" aria-selected="true"
                      class="btn btn-dark" style="color:white">></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!-- Stepper without Material :p -->
          <form [formGroup]="userprofileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active p-3" id="one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="one-tab">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div id="imagerpager" style="float: right; margin-right: 40px;">
                  <label style="margin-left: 20px;">Choose a profile picture.</label>
                  <br><br>
                  <input style="display:none" type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput />
                  <img [src]="imgSrc" (click)="fileInput.click()" style="border-radius: 5px;" alt="your image"
                    width="200" height="200" />
                </div>
                <!-- Name -->
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" id="exampleName" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    style="width:200px;" autocomplete="off">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('name', 'required')">Name is mandatory.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br><br>
                <label style="margin-right: 10px;">Gender:</label>
                <br>
                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="gender" (change)="changeImage()">
                  <mat-radio-button [checked]='true' name="gender" style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Male">Male
                  </mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button name="gender" style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Female">Female</mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button name="gender" style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Other">Other</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
                <br><br>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of Birth"
                    formControlName="dob">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker formControlName="dob" ngDefaultControl (selectedChanged)="onDate($event)">
                  </mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <label>Already a member? Click </label>
              <label id="memberalready"> <a routerLink="/core/login"> here </a><label>
                  to login.</label></label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div *ngIf="this.success">
              <div class="alert"
                style="padding-bottom:30px;width: 300px; height:20px; float: right; background-color: rgba(0, 255, 85, 0.4);"
                role="alert" id="passwordsNoMatchRegister">
                <span>
                  <p>Signup Succesful! Redirecting to login!</p>
                </span>
              </div>
              <mat-spinner style="zoom:0.2; position: absolute;top:700px; right:80px;"></mat-spinner>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="this.failure">
              <div class="alert"
                style="padding-bottom:30px;width: 300px; height:20px; float: right; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);"
                role="alert" id="passwordsNoMatchRegister">
                <span>
                  <p>Signup failed! Can't connect to server!</p>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" style="text-align: left;margin-top: -10px; margin-left: 30px;" id="two"
              role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="two-tab">
              <div class="form-group">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Email <span style="color: red;">*</span></mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp" autocomplete="off">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('email', 'required')">Email is mandatory.</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('email', 'email')">Enter a valid email.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email
                  with
                  anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <mat-form-field id="skeeverweever" style="margin-top:-50px;">
                <mat-label>Languages</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="skills" multiple>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skillList" [value]="skill">{{skill}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>

              <div class="form-group">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Password <span style="color: red;">*</span></mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('password', 'required')">Password is mandatory.</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div id="reenter" class="form-group" style="margin-top: -73px; margin-left: 220px">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Re-enter password <span style="color: red;">*</span></mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="password" formControlName="cnfpass" id="exampleConfirmPassword1">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="userprofileForm.get('cnfpass').invalid">Passwords don't match.
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <mat-form-field style="margin-top: -10px;">
                  <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="phone" id="phone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp"
                    autocomplete="off">
                  <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('phone', 'minlength')">Phone number should be 10 digits long.</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('phone', 'maxlength')">Phone number should be 10 digits long.</mat-error> -->
                  <mat-error *ngIf="userprofileForm.get('phone').invalid">Phone number can only contain 10 digits.
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <button type="submit"
                style="float:right; margin-top: -30px; margin-right:30px;background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0); color: whitesmoke;"
                class="btn" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content-main"></div>

<footer id="fh5co-footer" class="fh5co-bg" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-pb-md">
      <div class="col-md-4 fh5co-widget">
        <h3>A note with love.</h3>
        <br>
        <p style="color: rgb(172, 172, 172);">Random text.</p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3 style="float: right;">Reach out to us!</h3>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 col-lg-12 text-right">
          <ul class="fh5co-footer-links" style="color: rgb(172,172,172);">
            <p>
              <span class="material-icons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                location_on
              </span> New York, NY 10012, US</p>
            <p>
              <span class="material-icons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                alternate_email
              </span> abc@gmail.com</p>
            <p>
              <span class="material-icons" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                phone_iphone
              </span> 1111111</p>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="row copyright">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <p>
          <small class="block">&copy; 2020 | All Rights Reserved.</small>
          <small class="block">Powered by shoppingkart.com</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

This is my CSS code:

```css
#logo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: updown 1.5s ease infinite;

  @keyframes updown {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-10%);
    }

    50% {
      transform: translateY(10%);
    }

    100% {
      transform: translateY(-10%);
    }
  }

}

#carouselFinal {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-inner {
  z-index: 0;
  height: 577px;
}

// .card {
//   width: 1000px;
//   height: 1000px;
//   z-index: 1;
//   margin-top: 130px;
//   margin-left: 150px;
//   color: black;
//   background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
//   border-color: transparent;
// }

.tab-card,
.carousel-inner {
  position: absolute;
}



.tab-card {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  border-color: transparent;
}

.tab-card-header {
  background: none;
}

/* Default mode */
.tab-card-header>.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.tab-card-header>.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tab-card-header>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #737373;
  padding: 2px 15px;
}

.tab-card-header>.nav-tabs>li>a.show {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #007bff;
  color: #007bff;
}

.tab-card-header>.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.tab-card-header>.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


::ng-deep.mat-form-field-label {
  /*change color of label*/
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-underline {
  /*change color of underline*/
  background-color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
  /*change color of underline when focused*/
  background-color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-select-value {
  /*change color of underline*/
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-select-arrow {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border-color: white !important;
}


::ng-deep.mat-datepicker-toggle-default-icon {
  color: white !important;
}



.content-main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}

.fh5co-bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.fh5co-bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.fh5co-bg .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fh5co-bg-section {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

#fh5co-footer {
  padding: 7em 0;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-footer {
    padding: 3em 0;
  }
}

#fh5co-footer {
  position: relative;
}

#fh5co-footer .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#fh5co-footer h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-footer-links {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-footer-links li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-footer-links li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-footer-links li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-widget {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-footer .fh5co-widget {
    text-align: left;
  }
}

#fh5co-footer .fh5co-widget h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#fh5co-footer .copyright .block {
  display: block;
  color: cornsilk;
}


.btn-primary {
  background: #F85A16;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #F85A16;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  background: #f96c2f !important;
  border-color: #f96c2f !important;
}

.btn-primary.btn-outline {
  background: transparent;
  color: #F85A16;
  border: 1px solid #F85A16;
}

.btn-primary.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-primary.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-primary.btn-outline:active {
  background: #F85A16;
  color: #fff;
}

#memberalready {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    margin-left: -250px;
    // margin-top: -100px;
    // margin-top: 100px;
    // display: flex;
  }

  .tab-card-header {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-right: 120px;
  }

  #imagerpager {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: -320px;
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  #myTab {
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: -160px;
  }

  #memberalready {
    position: absolute;
    right: -68px;
    top: 633px;
  }

  #skeeverweever {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .p-3 {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

How do I do the responsive part? This code is behaving very weirdly.

I've deployed it on Firebase: https://shopping-cart-client-23081997.web.app/ if you wanna check it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine on Desktops but not on mobile or tablet because its not responsive. Making your site responsive should start from the ground up thus, the use of Relative measurement (%) not absolute measurement(px) like you've used. after if necessary thus if still it doesn't look good for certain break points then you use your media queries to spice it all up. in all responsiveness should be thought of right from the conceptualization to designing of the site.